# Subscripts and superscripts

Tags: latex3, expl3

In LaTeX2 `a_1`, `a_{123}` and `a^1`, `a^{123}` used to produce subscripts and superscripts respectively. In LaTeX3 superscripts still work the same way, but what happened to subscripts? I suspect the prominent role underscores play in LaTeX3 names has made a change necessary. I tried `\_` without success.

Comment: I think that when you're writing the actual content, you should have l3 syntax turned off.

Comment: Not sure what that means, can you elaborate further please.

Comment: It means that the `expl3` syntax should only be used in internal code, e.g, in packages etc or between `\ExplSyntaxOn ...\ExplSyntaxOff` and that on document level the `_` or `:` does not have this kind of meaning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Within the document, no change should be necessary. If you need to access subscripts within the code section where `_` is considered as a letter, you could use `\sb` which is defined in LaTeX as in plain TeX to have the same definition as the usual `_` token. Or if you want a L3 name for it `\c_math_subscript_token` (which is actually a `*` rather than a `_` but with the right catcode).

Comment: I am happy to report that `\sb` does the trick. Thank you David. Your reference to `*` and to `catcodes` is beyond my present capability to understand, but I am getting there.